# Convert DataFrameGroupBy to Dataframe (Keeping Values, no counting/summing etc)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am struggling with a problem and was hoping to get some help.

I have a DF that I want to groupby before merging with another DF, the only problem is, after I groupby, I am unable to merge it due to it being a 'DataFrameGroupBy' object.

The steps would be as follows:

Groupby the DF to consolidate the information into the 2 id's:

```
dftest = cov_DF.groupby(['lstID','covID'])
```

which results from a DF going from 121 rows to 101.  Then merge that on 'lstID' with a different df.

The answers I'm seeing on here are all related to users summing/counting/maxing and this doesn't apply to me.

To explain more of my situation, I'm iterating through XML and am appending certain things and creating a DF.  Now I want to group that DF into the columns above so there are no duplicates in lstID + covID and the columns then contain what I need.

An example of the table initially looks like this:

```
lstID | covID | covPrem | covBase | CovValue
1        1         10        NA        NA
1        1         NA        2         NA
```

And so I want that to turn into the below table, before I merge.

```
lstID | covID | covPrem | covBase | CovValue
1        1         10        2        NA
```

Should I be using a different function?  I feel like groupBy is working how I want it too but it's also annoying that it's not a DF so I can't merge until I change it back.

There will always be a value in lstID and covID

Answer (score 0):

When you groupby a datsframe, the index of dataframe become strange. You must reset index then use aggregate functions then you can merge with other dataframes. Also you must consider the new names of columns. This solve your problem with dataframe groupby object

```py
a = df.groupby(...).aggregate(...).reset_index()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what to aggregate by in this scenario

Comment: @ElliotGitter When you use groupby method you create a dataframe groupby object and if you use aggregate function, it convert to normal dayaframe object

Comment: This is what I have 'dftest = DF4_cov_all.groupby(['lstID','covID']).aggregate().reset_index()' and the error is 'Must provide 'func' or tuples of '(column, aggfunc)'

Comment: aggregate function need to pass a dictionary to it for work. You can see some examples in :.   https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html

Comment: Thanks, do you know how it could work in this situation?  I can't make much sense of it but will continue to google for more examples